# how to store data received from Twitter into MongoDb?

Tags: java, mongodb, twitter4j

I'm retrieving data from **twitter** and storing it in List<>.When trying to store it into **MongoDb** I'm getting the error message.
**Exception in "main " thread twitter4j.ResponseListImpl cannot be cast to com.mongodb.BasicDBObject**

```
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.List;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import com.mongodb.MongoException;

import twitter4j.ResponseList;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

public class SampleTwitter_data {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException, UnknownHostException, MongoException {
    ConfigurationBuilder cofigurationBuilder =new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cofigurationBuilder.setDebugEnabled(true)
        .setOAuthConsumerKey("----------")
        .setOAuthConsumerSecret("----------")
        .setOAuthAccessToken("----------")
        .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("----------");

     /**** Connect to MongoDB ****/
    Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);


    /**** Get database ****/
    // if database doesn't exists, MongoDB will create it for you
    DB db = mongo.getDB("mydb");

    /**** Get collection / table from 'sample' ****/
    // if collection doesn't exists, MongoDB will create it for you
    DBCollection table = db.getCollection("sample");

    /**** Getting Data From Twitter time line ****/
    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cofigurationBuilder.build());
    twitter4j.Twitter twitter=tf.getInstance();
      ResponseList<Status> status= twitter.getHomeTimeline();
      for(Status s:status)
      {
          /**** here i'm getting error****/

          BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
          document=(BasicDBObject) status;
            table.insert(document);

            /**** just to make sure that i'm retrieving data from Twitter ****/
     System.out.println(s.getId()+s.getUser().getName()+"      "+s.getText());

      }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Status` from Twitter4j isn't a Json, you should convert it first.

On your `cofigurationBuilder` you must set JSONStorEnabled true

```
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true).setOAuthConsumerKey(consumer_key")
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret("consumer_key_secret")
                .setOAuthAccessToken("access_token")
                .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("access_token_secret")
                .setJSONStoreEnabled(true);
```

And insted of

```
 BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
 document=(BasicDBObject) status;
```

You need to create the Json from status and parse it with mongo

```
                String json = TwitterObjectFactory.getRawJSON(status);
                DBObject dbObject = (DBObject) JSON.parse(json);
                collection.insert(dbObject);
```

Comment: After editing the `configurationBuilder`   getting error    **BasicBSONList can only work with numeric keys, not: [_id]**

Comment: `String json = TwitterObjectFactory.getRawJSON(status);
                DBObject dbObject = (DBObject) JSON.parse(json);
                collection.insert(dbObject);`  _here while inserting into collection i'm getting error.

Comment: collection is a DBCollection , you have to initialize it. Look this page https://coolprof.wordpress.com/2014/11/19/twitter-crawler-in-java-with-twitter4j/